# Trying to Split my Code Into Multiple Modules, Loop Doesn't Work

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn how to split up my code in modules to make it easier to understand.
This code is supposed to add the clicked fruit to the fruit basket. 
Problem: it only adds the last one.

I can make this work if I put the eventListener inside a for loop, but as far as I understand that's a no-no approach, since it's redundant to call the loop every time you click.

https://jsfiddle.net/8s4qgoLw/1/

```
var fruitBasket = document.querySelector('.fruit-basket');
var fruitList = document.querySelectorAll('.fruit-list li');

 for (var i = 0; i < fruitList.length; i++) {

 var fruit = fruitList[i];

}

function myFunction() {

  fruitBasket.appendChild(fruit); // or 'this'?

}

fruit.onclick = myFunction;
```

So how do I keep my JS modular, and make the onclick target each clicked fruit? I've tried using the this keyword in different ways — can't make it work.

I think there's a fundamental concept about loops I haven't quite understood yet, and I also have a hard time figuring out when to use what *type* of loop. Am I using the wrong type here?

Any help greatly appreciated! :-)

Answer (score 1):

> to add the clicked fruit to the fruit basket

use the following optimized approach:

```js
(function() {
  var fruitBasket = document.querySelector('#fruit-basket'),
      fruitList = document.querySelectorAll('.fruit-list')[0];

  fruitList.addEventListener('click', myFunction);
  
  // You only created one event listener. The target of the event is represented by e.target, and the target element the event listener is attached to is represented by e.currentTarget.
  function myFunction(e){
    if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
      fruitBasket.appendChild(e.target);
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
})();
```

```css
#fruit-basket {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<ul class="fruit-list">
    <li class="fruit-banana">Banana</li>
    <li class="fruit-apple">Apple</li>
    <li class="fruit-grape">Grape</li>
       <li class="fruit-pear">Pear</li>
  </ul>  
  
  <ul id="fruit-basket"></ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jqbak0ex/

Comment: Thank you! Question, does the fruit-basket have to be an ID, just curious about why. Is it because it's executing faster?

Comment: I suppose, logically there should be one basket for fruits. If fruit-basket had a class `fruit-basket` instead of ID - `querySelector` would return a set of elements, instead of one. But we use `id` which should be a unique identifier

Comment: Yeah I totally get your point. I'm trying to learn how to work with classes, which I find a lot harder than id's, so I practice mostly without id's, but in this case there's only on basket, so id makes sense.